# How can I click to walk to a mob, instead of attacking it?

Tags: diablo-iii

I started a wizard last night instead of sleeping and found something quite irritating in terms of usability.

When I wanted to walk into a mob of enemies, I clicked (left or right) and attacked with my ranged abilities. All I wanted to do is walk up to the enemies and cast a frost nova. I know I can do this by carefully clicking the ground next to them rather than clicking on the actual mob, however in the heat of battle, down a tight corridor infested with the foul undead, it is easier said than done.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can bind "Move" to a key which will cause your character to move towards your mouse cursor without attacking. It is unbound by default.

Comment: In addition to StrixVaria's answer, binding it to "Alt + click" (for example) makes perfect sense to me, forcing the character to move to the place you clicked.

Comment: This has the added benefit of letting you relax your mouse-hand while walking around, since you can now hold down a key to walk around instead of clicking the mouse ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You can click past the enemies, then use the ability when you pass through.

Comment: This is always what I've done...I never really click in these games, I'm always holding the button and moving the cursor, then releasing and clicking as I want to attack.

Answer (score 0):

A few alternative solutions:

- Bind a spell with a relatively long cooldown—but one you'd always want to keep active—to Mouse 1 (this only works well for some classes).  If you can't cast it due to cooldown (when you click) you'll "move" (actually try to attack; nearly the same if you're using a melee weapon).
- Click anywhere where there aren't mobs then drag towards where you want to go.