# How can I resurrect a player who is dead behind a boss?

Tags: diablo-iii

Last night I was fighting Belial on Hell, and my friend died in the top-left corner of the platform behind him. Every time I tried to click his gravestone to res him, I would simply attack Belial instead (even though my cursor would change to the "res player" hand). I tried zooming in with <kbd>Z</kbd> as well, but that didn't make a difference.

This has happened other times too, but its always been on bosses that move around, so I could kite them away from the body then run back and res.

Is there any other way to resurrect a player other than clicking their gravestone? Or failing that, is there a way to tell my character to not attack when clicking, so I can click on the gravestone?

(As a side note, I did finish killing Belial all by myself as a tanky-monk, even if it did take me 5-10 minutes since he had about 75% life when my friend died!)

Comment: [Bind the move key](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66285/5291) and see if that works (I haven't tried it, will test when I can).

Comment: @dpatchery I will try and resurrect the next dead player I see with the `Move` key and let you know if it works or not :) Providing the `Move` key can resurrect a player, this may work

Comment: For the record, no the Move key will not resurrect a player :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have fallen victim to the `not enough pixels` demon, preventer of resurrections and smudger of details.  Your best chance would come when he's leaning a little to the right, but even that's pretty fine.

If you can't get a good click on that gravestone, no, you cannot resurrect your friend.

This is another example in an appalling list of missing keyboard short cuts.