# Is there a button I can press to force movement?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I click to walk to a mob, instead of attacking it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66275/how-can-i-click-to-walk-to-a-mob-instead-of-attacking-it)

Similar to how I can hold shift to force my character to stand their ground and attack, is there a way to force them to move towards a position rather than attack whatever I happen to click? I'm finding on fights like phase 3 Belial in particular, I sometimes have issues clicking ground rather than him and attack rather than move, which gets me killed.

Answer (score 3):

There is an unbound "Move" command in the key bindings area of the menu. This should have the desired effect of just moving towards your cursor.

[image]

As you can see I've bound it to the number 2 button so that I can click around the larger enemies and trash loot.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. Interesting keybinds by the way.

Comment: I have a naga mouse so the 2 is right under my thumb